# Calculate $\int_{|z|=3} \frac{\sin 2z}{z^2(z^2-6z+8)}+\frac{e^{\frac{1}{z-2}}}{z-4} dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following complex integral:
$$\int_{|z|=3} \frac{\sin 2z}{z^2(z^2-6z+8)}+\frac{e^{\frac{1}{z-2}}}{z-4} dz$$

Since $z^2−6z+8=(z-2)(z-4)$ so
$$\int_{|z|=3} \frac{\sin 2z}{z^2(z^2-6z+8)}+\frac{e^{\frac{1}{z-2}}}{z-4} dz
=\int_{|z|=3} \frac{\sin 2z+z^2(z-2)e^{\frac{1}{z-2}}}{z^2(z-2)(z-4)}
dz.$$

I know $e^x=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k/k!$,

but I do not know how to simplify $\sin 2z+z^2(z-2)e^{\frac{1}{z-2}}$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Write
$$ \frac1{z^2(z-2)(x-4)}=\frac as+\frac b{z^2}+\frac c{z-2}+\frac d{z-4} $$
and use Cauchy’s Integration Formula for each term.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

For the second integral, the function $z \mapsto \frac{1}{z-4}$ is analytic inside the disk $|z|=3$. Expanding out the exponential and interchanging the sum and integrals, we obtain
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{|z|=3} \frac{\frac{1}{z-4}}{n!(z-2)^n} dz \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}\int_{|z|=3} \frac{\frac{1}{z-4}}{(z-2)^n}dz
\end{align}
(The $n=0$ case integrates to zero by Cauchy's theorem). The integrals can be simplifed with Cauchy's integral formula.